# Skip/Ignore Observable fromEvent subscription on a specific condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I would like to **skip/ignore** **subscription** on **fromEvent() observable** when a condition is true :
when `this.currentPosition === this.vc.getScrollPosition()[1]` I don't want to subscribe the observable because it's scrolling to next items directly and my goal is to wait for user interaction to scroll to the next item on my interface..

```
fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(1000)
)
    .subscribe(
        (event) => {

            const current = this.positions.find(e => e.name === this.currentSectionName);
            const indexOfCurrent = this.positions.indexOf(current);

            if (indexOfCurrent + 1 === this.positions.length) {
                // stay in the same position if it's the last item
                this.vc.scrollToPosition([0, current.position]);
                this.currentPosition = current.position;

            } else {
                // move to next position if it's not the last item
                const next = this.positions[indexOfCurrent + 1];
                this.vc.scrollToPosition([0, next.position]);
                this.currentPosition = next.position;
            }
        }

    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it in pipe.

```
fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
    filter( () => this.currentPosition !== this.vc.getScrollPosition()[1] ),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(1000)
)
```